# Where is the .asmx after I added a localhost webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

When I added service -> web service. The VS2008 added a App_WebReferences folder without a .asmx file. I see a .discomap file.

When I use the cascading drop down ajax control, it is looking for .asmx in the service path. Am I doing it wrong? I remember the early edition of Visual Studio added a .asmx file when you added a outside webservice reference.

**EDIT:**

I don't think I'm clear on my question. I have a ASP.net Webservice application that is setup on localhost/service. I want to reference to that service in my asp.net website. I first added the project to the service in the soultion add existing project then on my website i added the web reference via localhost/service. It now have a folder App_WebReferences and the service folder along with service.discomap, service.disco and service.wsdl

when i try to use the cascading drop down extension. the service path is looking for .asmx file so how do i setup the service path for the ajax extension?

Answer (score 2):

If the dropdown needs to call the web service, just give it the URL of the web service (ex: http://localhost/mywebservice/service1.asmx). I believe you'll also need to give it the name of the web method to call.

You won't need to add a web reference to your project unless you plan to call the web service manually.

Answer (score 0):

You added a reference to an external service. You'll want to create a new web service by right clicking on your project, then Add New Item and selecting Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you make a folder, say, WebServices, and add the asmx there, it'll place the .cs file in App_Code. If you have a web application project, I'm not sure where it would put it since there is no App_Code.